# Measure the quality of audio file .WAV after encryption my project language is VB.net

Tags: audio, vb.net-2010

what is the way to measure the quality of the audio file WAV after encryption my project language is VB.net

Answer (score 0):

After encryption the file will be indistinguishable from random bytes, there is no information about the original file without decrypting it with the encryption key.